# check for primality of a number

Tags: prime-numbers

Is `2^131 - 1` a prime number? if so how can i proof it, or if no how?
In the general is there a way for primality check for a `2^n - 1`
Thanks

Comment: google: mersenne primes

Comment: It's not prime, it's divisible by $263$ (the other prime factor is $10350794431055162386718619237468234569$). Generally, for Mersenne numbers, the Lucas-Lehmer test is the way.

Comment: 131 looks like a prime to me, so the basic requirement for messerne primes is satisfied. Yet it isn't a prime.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks good answer! but how you calculate other prime factor?!

Comment: Check that $\dfrac{2^{131}-1}{263}$ is a prime number using some other test. (Baillie-PSW + Pocklington certificate)

Comment: @DanielFischer okay thanks!

Comment: Reverse engineering Daniel's factor: $p=263\equiv7\pmod8$, so by (an extension of) quadratic reciprocity $2$ is quadratic residue modulo $p$. Therefore
$$2^{(p-1)/2}=2^{131}\equiv1\pmod{263}.$$

Comment: Or the other way round, $131 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, and $2\cdot 131 +1 = 263$ is prime, hence $263 \mid 2^{131}-1$.